# How do I manually change the Partition Type GUID

Tags: partition, macintosh

I did a Stupid thing without thinking first. I resized my dual boot Mac partition while in Windows.

Consequently, the resized Mac partition while still there cannot be read. I can scan for files. However, of course all I get it  `file00001.swift`  for example.

The current Partition Type is showing as - `DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC` (Windows Recovery Environment)

However it should be I believe - `7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC`

I have tried to alter this using Paragon Drive Manager but while it allows me to change some info it does not give access to that item.

So my question is;

Is there an app that lets me alter the Partition Type, or could someone tell me at what sector etc that data is located so I can do a Byte change perhaps ?

I am able to boot into Windows to view/whatever the bad Mac partition.

I am able to boot into an External Mac Drive OSx to view/whatever the bad Mac partition.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you already have Windows installed...

Windows `DiskPart` can easily do that.  Select the appropriate disk and partition, then use the `set id` subcommand.

```
set id=7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
```

Reference and documentation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/set-id

Comment: This did the trick, much appreciated. Don't have enough Reps to upvote.

Answer (score 5):

[Wikipedia has a description of the structure of the GPT partition table.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) In short, the protective legacy MBR is at block #0, the GPT partition table header at block #1, and the actual partition entries (128 bytes or more each) are located in block #2 and subsequent blocks.

At Sourceforge, there is a [command-line GPT partitioning utility `gdisk`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/files/gptfdisk/1.0.5/gdisk-binaries/) available not just as source code, but also as ready-for-use compiled executables for both Mac and Windows, which can change the partition type GUID to any value you want.

But if you plan to edit the partition table manually, there are two things you should know:

- There are two CRC32 checksums you must also update after editing the partition table, or else the edited partition table won't be valid, and the system will automatically use the backup partition table instead (see below).
- There is also a backup GPT partition table at the end of the disk, which needs to be modified too... with its own two CRC32 checksums.

Comment: Don't have enough Reps to upvote.

Comment: You can always mark an answer as accepted (green checkmark) if you wrote the question. It is even better than a regular upvote... but wait a few days first, perhaps there will be more answers still.

Comment: For anyone else coming across this let me say this answer I believe would have worked well if I did not luckily also have a dual boot Windows drive. As it turns out the answer by @fpmurphy below was easy for me to implement given my scenario.